# Consulta com campo como valor do IN

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa usando `INNER JOIN` na **tabela serviço**, o **campo agenda.serv_id** é uma string "vetor" e o valor dele no banco é: '1, 2'
Fiz 3 insert's no serviço, o único problema é que o `IN` só funciona quando uso (1,2) mas nesse caso eu não posso definir dessa forma pois cada agendamento tem o id de certo serviço

[image: Esse é o resultado esperado - que só ocorre quando utilizo os próprios números 1 e 2]

Mesmo convertendo o campo em inteiro o resultado é o mesmo, como não achei *nenhuma função de splt* no mysql o caso continua sem solução. Caso for necessário fazer o processo em back-end eu estou utilizando a linguagem de programação VisualBasic. Segue o código:

```
SELECT
    agenda.agen_id, 
    agenda.agen_data, 
    agenda.agen_turno, 
    group_concat(servico.serv_nome), 
    agenda.agen_total, 
    profissional.prof_comissao, 
    agenda.agen_obs, 
    profissional.prof_nome, 
    cliente.cli_nome 
FROM 
    agenda 
INNER JOIN servico ON servico.serv_id *in (agenda.serv_id)* 
INNER JOIN profissional ON agenda.prof_id = profissional.prof_id 
INNER JOIN cliente ON agenda.cli_id = cliente.cli_id
```

Comment: Wendel, conseguiu o resultado??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No banco de dados você tem algo tipo `1,2,3,4` e precisa pesquisar por apenas um valor, correto? 
Realmente o ideal seria isso não acontecer, você poderia ter uma tabela de relacionamento para armazenar o id do serviço e o id da agenda, evitando esse tipo de campo *vetor*.
Mas como acredito que você não pretende alterar a estrutura, sugiro uma solução *alternativa* (gambiarra): passe a armazenar o vetor iniciando e finalizando por vírgula, ex `,1,2,3,4,`; com isso, pode pesquisar por um número também iniciando e finalizando por vírgula:

```
SELECT
    agenda.agen_id, 
    agenda.agen_data, 
    agenda.agen_turno, 
    group_concat(servico.serv_nome), 
    agenda.agen_total, 
    profissional.prof_comissao, 
    agenda.agen_obs, 
    profissional.prof_nome, 
    cliente.cli_nome 
FROM 
    agenda 
INNER JOIN servico ON 1 = 1 --a condição daqui será validada no where
INNER JOIN profissional ON agenda.prof_id = profissional.prof_id 
INNER JOIN cliente ON agenda.cli_id = cliente.cli_id 
WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT(',',servico.serv_id,','), agenda.serv_id) > 0
```

Utilizei o [**`CONCAT`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) para alterar o id do serviço apenas na pesquisa e o [**`LOCATE`**](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php) no lugar do in para validar se o código (*string*) existe no vetor de *ids* (a função retorna > 0 se existir a *substring* na *string* original).

OBS: não indico você pesquisar diretamente o código (*id*) pois pode retornar dados errados (ex: a pesquisa por 1 retornaria verdade para o id 11)